# Change Numeric Value to Text - jQuery / NivoSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, nivo-slider

I'm trying to change the numeric navigation, in the example below, to actual text links.

So `'1'` could be `'Football'`, `'2'` could be `'Ice Hockey'` and so on...

How do I achieve this using the [NivoSlider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/4/) code?

I have moved the code to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JSNuU/ in case this is more helpful.

I would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: No real documentation on that site. In that case, you could try to alter the div after domready with something like $('.nivo-control[rel="0"]').html('nemo');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Nivo does not provide a hook to control the navigation, other than to replace it with a series of images. The numbers are hard-coded in:

```
nivoControl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+ i +'"><img src="'+ child.attr('rel') + '" alt="" /></a>');
```

You can however change them after-the-fact if you'd like: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JSNuU/3/)

```
var navNames = ['one','two','three','four'];
jQuery('.nivo-control').each(function(i){
    $(this).text( navNames[i] )
})
```

Comment: Brilliant stuff, Sinetheta!!! That worked perfectly. Many thanks for taking the time to look at it and help out. Green tick coming up :-)

Comment: Nitpick: if there are two sliders on the same page, this will have unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Indeed it will. However in that (unlikely) case it is a simple matter of being more specific with your targeting. If anyone would like a more general solution I would happy to oblige ;)

Answer (score 1):

The plugin doesn't seem to support this. However, you can use a jQuery loop to hack in the new labels after the plugin has created them:

```
jQuery('.nivo-controlNav').each(function() { // in case there's more than one
    var arrLinks = ['one','two','three','four'];
    jQuery(this).children('a').each(function(i,el) {
        jQuery(el).text(arrLinks[i]);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/JSNuU/5/

Answer (score 0):

nivo does not support this, but after a quick look at their uncompressed source it could be added in easily.  On line 168 after checking if thumbs are toggled, it has this simple line:

```
nivoControl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+ i +'">'+ (i + 1) +'</a>');
```

This can be adapted as such:

```
nivoControl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+ i +'">'+ kids.eq(i).attr("title") +'</a>');
```

Or `alt` or `name` or even a data attribute:

```
nivoControl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+ i +'">'+ kids.eq(i).data("caption") +'</a>');
```

not that anyone would want to take that much time to fix this for something you only really use once or twice. ;)

if you do though, be sure to re-compress it after the fact to improve download speed.